# storyboard上でUIViewからsegueは張れないのか

Tags: ios, storyboard

storyboard上でUIViewから他のviewControllerにsegueが張りたいです。
UIButtonは右ドラッグでsegueが張れるのですが、classをUIButtonに変えてもsegueが張れません。
ソース上から指定する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: Attlibute Inspectorを表示すると「View」のままですね。Storyboardファイルの「Open As」-「Source Code」でviewタグをbuttonタグに直接書き換えればセグウェが引っ張れるようになりますが、XMLをみて、難易度的に直接編集できそうですか？

Comment: ボタンにイメージを貼り付けるほうが、はるかに作業コストが低いと思うのだが？

Comment: @dokubeko    試しに書き換えてみた所、xcodeがクラッシュしましたw

Comment: @Harawo  imageをボタン文字列の上に配置したいんですがソレってUIButtonで出来るんでしょうか？

Comment: それと、質問された内容の根本的な原因は、ストーリーボード上で元々UIViewだったものを後からUIButtonに変更しても、UIButtonとして扱われてないことだと思うので、「ストーリーボード上で既に配置したビューの元クラスを正しく変更する方法」という感じにするとより的確な回答が求められる気がします

Comment: Harawoさんの言うように、メンテナンス性やそもそものUI設計として私もUIButtonで実現した方が自然に思います。参考になる記事がありましたので、お節介とは思いますが記載させていただいておきます。http://xoyip.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/10/215106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

方法が分かりました。
segueを張りたいviewに対してTapGestureRecognizerを追加し、
そのTapGestureRecognizerからviewcontrollerにsegueを張る事が出来ます。